# Bootstrap modal is not turning into a modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am using Bootstrap 5 and is trying to have a modal appear when a button is clicked. I have this hyperlink as a button

```
<a class="btn btn-lg btn-transparent btn-delete" id="settlement_Delete" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#deleteConfirmationModal">
                    <i class="fas fa-ban me-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>Delete
                </a>
```

I have the modal defined like this

```
<div id="deleteConfirmationModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-lg modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h2 class="modal-title">Delete Confirmation</h2>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Are you sure you want to delete this item?
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button id="closeDeleteConfirmation" type="button" class="btn btn-cancel" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="Delete()">Delete</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that when the modal appears the background is hidden and the modal covers the entire screen (see image below) vs a dialogue box like the example on thier site. I suspect that I am missing some css or javascript but is unable to track down what is missing. Any suggestion on how to proceeed/ troubleshoot?

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity=

// Required
@import "../lib/bootstrap-5.1.3/scss/functions";
@import "../lib/bootstrap-5.1.3/scss/variables";
@import "../lib/bootstrap-5.1.3/scss/mixins";

// Variable Overrides
@import '_config/variables';

// Required
@import "../lib/bootstrap-5.1.3/scss/utilities";

// Bootstrap Framework
@import "../lib/bootstrap-5.1.3/scss/root";
@import "../lib/bootstrap-5.1.3/scss/reboot";
@import "../lib/bootstrap-5.1.3/scss/type";
@import "../lib/bootstrap-5.1.3/scss/images";
@import "../lib/bootstrap-5.1.3/scss/containers";
@import "../lib/bootstrap-5.1.3/scss/grid";
@import "../lib/bootstrap-5.1.3/scss/tables";
@import "../lib/bootstrap-5.1.3/scss/forms";
@import "../lib/bootstrap-5.1.3/scss/buttons";
@import "../lib/bootstrap-5.1.3/scss/transitions";
@import "../lib/bootstrap-5.1.3/scss/dropdown";
@import "../lib/bootstrap-5.1.3/scss/button-group";
@import "../lib/bootstrap-5.1.3/scss/nav";
@import "../lib/bootstrap-5.1.3/scss/navbar";
@import "../lib/bootstrap-5.1.3/scss/card";
@import "../lib/bootstrap-5.1.3/scss/alert";
@import "../lib/bootstrap-5.1.3/scss/accordion";
@import "../lib/bootstrap-5.1.3/scss/breadcrumb";
@import "../lib/bootstrap-5.1.3/scss/pagination";
@import "../lib/bootstrap-5.1.3/scss/badge";
@import "../lib/bootstrap-5.1.3/scss/alert";
@import "../lib/bootstrap-5.1.3/scss/progress";
@import "../lib/bootstrap-5.1.3/scss/list-group";
@import "../lib/bootstrap-5.1.3/scss/close";
@import "../lib/bootstrap-5.1.3/scss/toasts";
@import "../lib/bootstrap-5.1.3/scss/modal"; <--------- modal 
@import "../lib/bootstrap-5.1.3/scss/tooltip";
@import "../lib/bootstrap-5.1.3/scss/popover";
@import "../lib/bootstrap-5.1.3/scss/carousel";
@import "../lib/bootstrap-5.1.3/scss/spinners";
@import "../lib/bootstrap-5.1.3/scss/offcanvas";

// Helpers
@import "../lib/bootstrap-5.1.3/scss/helpers";

// Utilities
@import "../lib/bootstrap-5.1.3/scss/utilities/api";
```

[image]

Comment: Have you inspected the modal in the browser to see what styles are affecting it? It's going to be hard for us to help from this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the [bootsrap.css](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css) as your html code is working fine.

```
<a class="btn btn-lg btn-transparent btn-delete" id="settlement_Delete" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#deleteConfirmationModal">
    <i class="fas fa-ban me-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>Delete
</a>
    
<div id="deleteConfirmationModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-lg modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h2 class="modal-title">Delete Confirmation</h2>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    Are you sure you want to delete this item?
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button id="closeDeleteConfirmation" type="button" class="btn btn-cancel" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="Delete()">Delete</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Please check the running [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8pf1407z/)

Comment: I updated my post. I have included all the boostrap scss that I am using which includes more than the default that boostrap.scss is using. Perhaps it is clashing?

Answer (score 0):

From reading the question, your entire issue seems to be based around having a full screen modal rather than a tiny box that appears in the middle of the screen. I think this is because you are using `modal-dialog-lg`. Try `modal-dialog-sm` and see how that looks.

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-sm modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
```